# How do i show that $\psi : D_n \rightarrow D_m$ defined by $\psi(\mu^i \rho^j) = \delta^i \gamma^j$ is a homormophism from $D_n$ to $D_m$ where n =qm

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

Let $n = dm$
Consider these groups:
$D_n = \langle \mu, \rho \mid \mu^2 = \rho^n = \epsilon, \mu\rho = \rho^{-1}\mu \rangle$

$D_m = \langle \delta, \gamma \mid \delta^2 = \gamma^m = \epsilon, \delta\gamma = \gamma^{-1}\delta \rangle$

$\psi : D_n \rightarrow D_m$ defined by $\psi(\mu^i \rho^j) = \delta^i \gamma^j$
show that $\psi$ is a homomorphism
This is what  i tried:

$\psi((\mu^i \rho^j)(\mu^x \rho^y))$ = $\psi(\mu^i \mu^x\rho^{-j} \rho^y))$ = $\psi(\mu^{i+x} \rho^{-j+y})$ = $\delta^{i+x} \gamma^{-j+y}$ = $\delta^{i}\delta^{x} \gamma^{-j}\gamma^{y}$

However, from here I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you know that these define dihedral groups?

Comment: @Shaun Yes, I am aware. I used properties from the dihedral groups in my attempt but i still can't find a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially done, since by the same manipulations you also have
$$
\delta ^i \delta ^x \gamma ^{-j}\gamma ^y=\delta ^i \gamma ^j \delta ^x \gamma^y=\psi (\mu ^i \rho ^j) \psi(\mu ^x \rho^y)
$$
Then since $n=dm$ you also have $\psi(\epsilon)=\psi (\mu ^0\rho^0) =\epsilon$.
Finally you have to prove that $\psi(g^{-1})=\psi(g)^{-1}$. But this simply follows from the two facts above and
$$
\psi(g)\psi(g^{-1})=\psi(gg^{-1})=\psi(\epsilon)=\epsilon
$$

Comment: $pu = up^{-1} $but you cant do the contrary no ? why did you just assume you could in your proof.

Comment: If you multiply both members of $pu=up^{-1}$ on the left by $p^{-1}$ and on the right by $p$ you get $up=p^{-1}u$.